# How to find table type for a data element?

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I create a new function modul in abap which should return a list of the data element `AGVAL`.

AFAIK there are two ways now:

1. I use an already available table type
2. I create a new table type

How to do this kind of introspection? I would like to now if there is already a table type with one column, which is of type AGVAL?

Answer (score 6):

you can enter your element type in TA SE11 as Data Type.
Go to display and use the Where-Used-List to search for table fields / strucure fields to find the usage of this data element.

Regards
Max

Answer (score 4):

I don't know any option else but using SQL to query the ABAP dictionary directly.

For instance, this query extracts all table types having a structure whose first component has the data element `SO_TEXT255` (and which is not embedded in a nested structure) :

```
SELECT * FROM DD40L
  WHERE ROWKIND = 'S'
    and ROWTYPE in (
      select TABNAME from DD03L
        where POSITION = 1
          and ROLLNAME = 'SO_TEXT255' )
```

Of course, it doesn't restrict to structures with only this one component but you may adapt it a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not stick purely to ABAP-way it is done via SE11 in a very simple way.

1. Search by table types

[image]

2. Choose search type as "by reference line"

[image]

3. That's it!

[image]